# Read Excel File using OLEDB Connection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to read a excel file and put data into a datatable in C#.When I try with Excel 97-2003 file format ( .xls ) it is working fine .But when I try with Excel workbook format (.xlsx ) it is getting a error like following,

"External table is not in the expected format."

Here is my code segment.

```
string file_name = null;

OpenFileDialog file_d = new OpenFileDialog();
file_d.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls";
file_d.Title = "Select Attendance Record";

if (file_d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    file_name = file_d.FileName;
}

String ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file_name + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

try
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

    MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
    DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
    MyConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Please help me with the error.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: xlsx files should be read with Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0

Comment: thanks Steve .it solved the problem...

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + your sorce + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;");
Perhaps this is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

'.xlsx' and other Office files since Office 2007 are in XML format. You can use [OpenXML](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-Sdk) to read or write to them.